# Solve a system of backward and forward coupled equations in Python

Tags: python

Is there a solver for a system of coupled equations where some are forward (with an initial condition) and some are backward (with a final condition)?

```
dx(t)/dt = f(t, y(t))
x(0) = c_f

dy(t)/dt = b(t, x(t))
y(T) = c_b
```